# TableLayout problems

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, tablelayout

I'm having some problems aranging a tablelayout. The way i've written the XML doesnt seem to show as i think it should when it appears on the screen. I want each column of my first tablerow to be equal in size, with its contents centered but what i am getting is the first 2 column bigger than the second two.

My XML code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblIP"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/ip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtIP"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:text="@string/ip_address" >

    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPort"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/port" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPort"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number" />
</TableRow>
```

How it appears:
[image: table layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblIP"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtIP"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="@string/ip_address" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblPort"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/port" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPort"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to set the `android:layout_width` attribute to `0dp` and keep the `android:layout_weight` as `1` on the child views